# .htaccess rewrite/redirect directory to subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain

In my website's root `.htaccess` file, I have the code shown here to redirect to the `www` version, as well as hide the `index.php` page if in the directory root:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://www.example.com/ [R=301,NC,L]
```

Within this site, I have an API located at `http://www.example.com/app/API/`

I would like to do two things:

1. Perform all API calls via the subdomain `http://api.example.com/` (but really process them at the original URL, `http://www.example.com/app/API/`)
2. Redirect all traffic from `http://www.example.com/app/API/` to `http://api.example.com/`, keeping all query parameters in tact.

What I'm asking seems fairly simple, but for whatever reason I can't figure it out (even after extensive searching). I can set up the subdomain through my hosting provider, but I'd rather use `.htaccess` for further customization.

Comment: Are both `www.example.com` and `api.example.com` pointing to the same document root?

Comment: Currently, there is no `.htaccess` impacting the subdomain. Does that answer your question? @JonLin

Comment: Also, I do not want ALL calls to the domain to be forwarded to the subdomain. Only calls to the `app/API/` directory. The main website still exists on the main example.com domain root

Comment: @adamdehaven if the main domain and subdomain do not share the same DocumentRoot that would not be possible. If you access `http://api.example.com/app/API/` does it lead you to the same result as accessing `http://www.example.com/app/API/`?

Comment: No, that should be not the case - see the original post. I just thought there would be a way to rewrite the URL in the browser so that either way the URL reads `http://api.example.com/`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^api\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^app/API/(.*)$ http://api.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^api\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app/API/$1 [L]
```